# Declare function in static library, define it in application that uses that same library

Tags: c++, c

I would like to declare a function called `foo()` inside of a static library and call it from within the static library. However, I would like to force the user of the application to provide the definition of `foo()`. Is something like this possible in C/C++?

So as an example imagine this to be the static library:

**In foo.h:**

```
void foo();
```

**In foo.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
   foo();
   return 0;
}
```

Then in the application that uses this static library:

**In app.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo() {
    // Do something here...
}
```

I imagine this must be what e.g. the Win32 API does with their `WinMain()` function, which essentially replaces the usual `main()`. How does this work though? In the above example the static library would of course not compile, due to an `undefined reference` to `foo()`.

Comment: A "static library" is not going to have a `main()`. Your question is confusing.

Comment: Are you ure you're not looking for an interface or callbacks?

Comment: Declarations don't exist in libraries, they are source level constructs. *declare a function called "foo()" inside of a static library* is a meaningless phrase. And there's no such thing as C/C++.

Comment: @Sam: It's perfectly fine for `main` to be provided by a library, and quite a few frameworks do this.

Comment: @n.m. Then declarations do not exist in applications, too, because it is a source level construct. Both applications and libraries have source code. Both applications and libraries are compiled. Both applications and libraries "loses" its declarations while being compiled. There is completely no difference between applications and libraries.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad "Then declarations do not exist in applications" Indeed they do not. Why is this surprising? "There is completely no difference between applications and libraries", True. So?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You already know how.

Your confusion lies in

> the static library would of course not compile, due to an "undefined reference"

But "undefined reference" is not a compile error -- it is generated by the linker.  And a static library is just an unlinked collection of compiled object files.  (Plus maybe an index, so the linker can find which object files it needs efficiently without scanning each one)

When the linker does run, it will be provided with both the application objects and the library, and nothing will be left unresolved.

Dynamic libraries are created via a linking step; static libraries aren't.

Comment: Now I feel extra dumb. You hit the nail on the head, i accidentally tried compiling a dynamic library rather than a static one, hence the undefined reference error. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, this kind of functionality is usually achieved with function pointers.

```
//header.h
typedef int(*add_func)(int, int);

int perform_add(int a, int b, add_func func) {
    return func(a,b);
}

//In User .cpp file
#include<Header.h>

int my_add_func(int a, int b) {
    return a; //Ooooh, edgy!
}

int my_other_add_func(int a, int b) {
    return a + 2 * b; //Don't cut yourself with that edge!
}

int main() {
    int val = perform_add(1, 5, my_add_func);
    val = perform_add(val, val, my_other_add_func);
    return 0;
}
```

In C++, we usually use `std::function` to represent these pointers, since they're easier to read, and can also hold functors and lambdas.

```
//header.h
typedef std::function<int(int,int)> add_func;

int perform_add(int a, int b, add_func const& func) {
    return func(a,b);
}

//In User .cpp file
#include<Header.h>

int my_add_func(int a, int b) {
    return a; //Ooooh, edgy!
}

int my_other_add_func(int a, int b) {
    return a + 2 * b; //Don't cut yourself with that edge!
}

int main() {
    int val = perform_add(1, 5, my_add_func);
    val = perform_add(val, val, my_other_add_func);
    //The following would not have compiled if we just used function pointers.
    val = perform_add(val, 17, [val](int a, int b) {return a + b + val;});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a viable alternative, but you haven't answered the question.

Comment: Either that, or have the library provide an abstract base class with pure virtual methods, then the consumer of the library needs to define a subclass with those virtual methods filled in.  Depends on the situation which one I'd use.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I would like to force the user of the application to provide the definition of `foo()`. Is something like this possible in C/C++?

You're already doing that implicitly. The library you have has a reference to `foo()` as it was declared in the header.

If the application doesn't provide a definition for `foo()`, you'll end up with a linking error.
To fix that, a user of your library needs to provide a definition of `foo()`.

Your static library can be compiled though, the linker error will occur only if you create an executable or shared library using it.

You should document that in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing technically wrong with leaving a function undefined in a library and expecting the application to provide it. This is actually done by at least one mainstream product called `lex` (your computer may have a free implementation called `flex`). This is not a good style though, and `lex`/`flex` continue to use it mostly for backwards compatibility.

It is recommended to pass user functions to library code as callbacks at run time, rather than bind them at link time.

Incidentally, the `lex` library also contains a definition of `main`, so this, too, is not unheard of.